# Why does my AG Grid not render Row Styling correctly?

Tags: css, angular

So i have a problem with my grid. On the initial loading my grid looks like this:
[image]

Basically everything seems fine until i scroll to the right.
Than my grid looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, on the last column the row styling is not applied and I was wondering if there is a fix for that since i can't seem to figure it out!
Thanks for helping

Comment: Could you please explain what is wrong in image 2?

Comment: updated in the post

Answer (score 0):

Can you use overflow: hidden then tell us what happend after using that?

Comment: Where should i use it? Column? or better said on which class

Comment: That parent which has scroll.
if you use overflow:hidden it would be hidden.